# How can I get the username of the logged in user in Django?

Tags: django

I'M new to Django, looking to get first name and last name of the logged-in user in Django,
login method am using LDAP authentication.

when i login as admin i was able to see the LDAP user in User information tab.

Tried request.user.first_name didn't work, is there any other method to get the details?

Comment: Thanks for your input, but either didn't work

When i print(request.user)  it shows - Anonymous User

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to get first name, last name and all details of the logged in user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
first_name = User.objects.get(username=request.user).first_name
last_name = User.objects.get(username=request.user).last_name
```

In the same way you can get any attribute of the user. For logged in users, you have to use the keyword `request.user`.

Comment: Thanks Sai Santosh, your suggestion worked, it's my mistake in code where ldap user in lowercase in user model and i was trying with upper case

Answer (score 0):

**There is two method in AbstractUser class, you can use this**

```
request.user.get_full_name()
request.user.get_short_name()
```

*get_short_name will return first_name*